# Can't find .XSL file embedded in project DLL

Tags: c#, xslt, embedded-resource

Quick question that's wrecked my morning and is driving me nuts.

I have a small project that includes a DLL from another project. The DLL has an XSL file embedded in it that I want to extract and apply to a webbrowser control.

I have no problem with extracting / accessing embedded resources in the main EXE file, but I cannot find the means of accessing it in the DLL!?

I've tried:

- "SolutionName.DllName.Resource.xsl"
- "ExeName.DllName.Resource.xsl"
- "ProjectNamespace.DllNamespace.Resource.xsl"

...and pretty much every permutation thereof, but it's never able to find it.

I don't have a dot-notation reference for it in C# to use with `nameof()`, and I can't find any apparent reference / access to it with:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

So, what's the correct naming (or other?) method for retrieving this file?

In case any of this helps, here's some additional details:

**Project Name:** *DataBuilder*
**Project Namespace:** *DataBuilder*
**DLL Name:** *CobCommon*
**DLL Namespaces:** *CobCommon, CobCommon.Classes, CobCommon.Classes.Data, CobCommon.Winforms, CobCommon.WinForms.Controls*
**XSL Resource Name:** *XmlFormating.xsl*

The specified resource file operation is "Embedded Resource" and it's located in the "root" area of the DLL project.

Accessing `global::` gives me *CobCommon*, and *DataBuilder* amongst the available choices, but *CobCommon* doesn't have either a `.Properties` or a `.Resources` option, and *DataBuilder* which does have `.Properties.Resources` gives "Culture" as the only reference.

The XSL file *is* listed on the DLL Project's "Properties|Resources|Files" tab.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you use `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("CobCommon.dll")` to get a handle on your assembly, then do the normal `GetManifestResourceStream()` thing?

Comment: Entered exactly as given, it returns, a "File Not Found" exception. Adding ".\" to the front of the name returns a "File Access" exception, which I assume is because it's locked by the running executable that's it's bound to?

Comment: Exception: *System.IO.FileLoadException: {"Could not load file or assembly '.\\\\CobCommon.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)":".\\\\CobCommon.dll"}"*
I don't know why it's putting ".\\\\" in there: the string as it's entered in the editor is simply `@".\CobCommon.dll"`

Comment: Hmm.  How about `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly()` using a type from inside the assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GetExecutingAssembly()` will probably always refer to *your* assembly. Instead, create an instance of some innocuous, (hopefully) simple object declared in that external DLL, then use that instance object's...

```
<object-from-DLL>.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("what.youre.looking.for")
```

to get a stream handle to your embedded object.

Comment: This ultimately pointed me in the direction of a solution, though I opted for a more genericised version that I could use again in the future (via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` then searching through them for one with a name matching the requested resource). 

As you correctly surmised, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` only refers to the base project/exe while going through `AppDomain` instead of `Reflection.Assembly` provided a means to find and access external resources!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, rather than going to all the trouble of actually instantiating an object just to call `.GetType()` on it, couldn't you just substitute `typeof(ClassNameFromDLL).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("what.youre.looking.for")` instead?

Comment: So, because the way I needed to use the content of the text file as a Stream, and the method I wrote (below) returns the contents as a string, I ended up using the variation of your idea (using `typeof(ClassInDll).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("thing,youwantto,load")`) and it works perfectly, so I gave you the answer credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this was the way that I finally managed to put together a generic function to retrieve *any* text-encoded embedded resource from any project assembly (and that's working as intended in my project):

First, I extended the `Assembly` class to facilitate grabbing just the relevant leading portion of `Assembly.FullName` that we need to use to search for the requested resource:

```
/// <summary>Adds a function to dereference just the base name portion of an Assembly from the FullName.</summary>
/// <returns>The extracted base name if able, otherwise just the FullName.</returns>
public static string ExtractName(this Assembly root)
{
    string pattern = @"^(?<assy>(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+[.]?)+)(?>,).*$", work = root.FullName;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(work, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (matches.Count > 0) return matches[0].Groups["assy"].Value;

    if (work.IndexOf(",") > 3) return work.Substring(0, work.IndexOf(','));

    return root.FullName;
}
```

Then I wrote this function to search for the specified assembly + embedded resource file and return its contents as a string, if found:

```
/// <summary>Searches all loaded assemblies in a project for the specified embedded resource text file.</summary>
/// <returns>If the specified resource is found, its contents as a string, otherwise throws a DllNotFoundException.</returns>
/// <exception cref="DllNotFoundException"></exception>
public static string FetchAssemblyResourceFile(string name)
{
    Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    int i = -1; while ((++i < assemblies.Length) && !Regex.IsMatch(name, "^(" + assemblies[i].ExtractName() + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) ;
    if (i < assemblies.Length)
    {
        try {
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = assemblies[i].GetManifestResourceStream(name))
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception innerExc)
        {
            Exception result = new Exception("The requested resource (\"" + name + "\") was not found.");
            result.InnerException = innerExc;
            throw result;
        }
    }
    throw new DllNotFoundException("The requested assembly resource (\"" + name + "\") could not be found.");
}
```